# Batch - FOR loop issue

Tags: batch-file

The file which I am processing (param.txt) is tab delimited and the contents of the first column are _ delimited.

param.txt

```
ONE_one  two  three
FOUR_four  five  six
SEVEN_seven  eight  nine
```

I've created below script to process this file:

```
@echo off & setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=    " %%G in ('type param.txt') do (
  for /f "tokens=1 delims=_" %%a in ('echo %%G') do (
    echo %%a -- %%b -- %%H -- %%I
  )
)
endlocal & goto :EOF
```

This produces the below output:

```
ONE -- %b -- two -- three
FOUR -- %b -- five -- six
SEVEN -- %b -- eight -- nine
```

What needs to be rectified in the script to get it to print the "value" instead of %b?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing `tokens=1` with `tokens=1,2`.

Note also that you can do the extraction with a single for loop, since you can specify multiple delimiters:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=_ " %%G in ('type param.txt') do (
  echo %%G -- %%H -- %%I -- %%J
)
```

Answer (score 0):

JRL got the correct answer given the scenario you presented.

If a value in your 1st column ever might contain a value like "seven_seven_seven", then you probably only want to break on the first `_`. In that case you want to use "tokens=1*" in your 2nd FOR statement. That way %%b will contain "seven_seven".